# I want to allow my flutter app to access images & other files on my MySQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, jwt, hotlinking

On my webserver (MySQL). I implemented hotlink protection which allow requests from allowed domains only. now i want to add my mobile app in the access list so i can access the files or images in the app easily. is there any way to achieve this funcationality?

If i disable the hotlink protection for all domains then mobile app can access the files easily. Please help me to resolve this issue so i can access images & files with hotlink protection.

I tried my best but still no progress.

Comment: Webservers !== MySQL ???

Comment: [This article](https://santosenoque.medium.com/how-to-connect-flutter-app-to-mysql-web-server-and-phpmyadmin-e100f47bfb82) shall help you